# Real world applications of Fermat's Last theorem

Tags: soft-question

I am trying to edit a high school paper on Wiles and the phases of discovery along the way to his proof are beyond my poor math skills.  I would be grateful for a plain English explanation of the Galois Representation, the  Kolyvagin-Flach method and the Iwasawa theory, as well as Fermat's Last Theorem ?  Or a way to explain how these ideas are applied in the non-pure-math world?  I was not even able to find an incomprehensible definition of the Kolyvagin-Flack method.  Thank you from one who admires the numerate from afar.

Comment: Why Fermat Numbers? By the way, I don't know if such explanation would be able to fit in such a tiny space :3

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately such an answer is likely impossible, as it is extremely hard to explain en brief. There are entire books devoted to the topic. I think that *Fermat's Enigma: the Epic Quest to Solve the World's Greatest Unsolved Problem* is a pretty good one, but you're unlikely to condense it to a few pages. Reading it might increase your understanding though.

Answer (score 0):

We waited hundreds of years for a proof of FLT. We will probably wait another hundred years or more than a proof that a normal person can understand.

I downloaded a copy of his proof, and didn’t understand a thing. I only noticed that all the signs that allow me to identify crackpots were missing. It all felt right.